# Python: fence-post caused by for loop

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

I am trying to build a basic random serial number generator in Python, which inserts each generated S\N into a list.
In the end of every generated S\N there is an unnecessary dash (-). For example:

```
XXXX-YYYY-ZZZZ-NNNN-
```

Code:

```
import random
import string

x = ""
l = [] # A blank list

for y in range(0,3): # Creating 3 different serial numbers
    for t in range(0,4): # Creating 4 sections to each S\N and seperating them with a dash (-)
        for i in range(0, 5): # Creating a 5 letters combination
            x += random.choice(string.ascii_letters)

        x += "-" # Causes problem since printed 4 times instead of 3   
    l.append(x)
    x = ""
print(l)
```

Output:

```
['GzWFP-Owoyk-NNKBk-RKZBm-', 'nxTtS-aGVff-yVfLo-WQVJN-', 'HUmTd-XzSSK-weSKs-BHNSv-']
```

I tried different variations but none of them seems to work.
Best Regards.

Comment: You can for instance use a temporary list to which you add your four latter groups and then do `'-'.join(that_list)`.

Comment: Why are you doing it? Just use uuid4 from uuid module

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply [rstrip()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rstrip) the offending `'-'` before appending your SN to its list of serial numbers:

```
# create SN like above, change l.append(x) to: 
l.append(x.rstrip('-')) # removes the -from the right end before appending
```

---

If you need to produce lots and fast, you should draw all characters needed *at once* instead of *one character at a time* and simply put the spacers between the groups like so:

```
import random
import string

def createSN(groups = 4, charPerGroup = 5, spacer = '-'):
    """Create a serial number with 'groups' groups consisting 
    of 'charPerGroup' chars with 'spacer' between groups."""

    total = groups * charPerGroup
    # creates all characters with one call to random
    chars = random.choices(string.ascii_letters, k = total)
    # uses list slicing and string joining to divide created characters 
    # in groups and puts the spacer character between groups
    return spacer.join( ''.join(chars[i:i+charPerGroup]) for i in range(0,total,amount))


# create a list of 3 SN:
l = [createSN() for _ in range(3)]  

print(l)
```

Output:

```
['ONHVQ-PvIvo-ZVdRU-HYCZz', 'BWQnt-nRCGG-raoVt-XEWif', 'mMPDd-KakQR-BDkRG-MdqBX']
```

This is similar and (but I think) superior to @CoryKramer solution, he still draws each character individually - and using a function makes it a tad more clear what happens.

Answer (score 3):

This is a bit terse for a one-liner, but it can be done using `str.join` in a list comprehension.
Basically you can use `random.choice` over the `string.ascii_letters` for the length of each substring you want, then `'-'.join` to concatenate the substrings using hyphens, then repeat that for the number of total items that you want.

```
>>> from random import choice
>>> from string import ascii_letters
>>> ['-'.join(''.join(choice(ascii_letters) for j in range(5)) for i in range(4)) for k in range(3)]
['HjPVn-sZFRG-RooXu-PicTA', 'dEZPM-sSXKx-XWWAz-qxyUd', 'BHyHE-fhGWb-sDutN-QIrJV']
```